# Unable to create Serverless VPC Access Connector when using SharedVPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

## Background:

- I have a Shared VPC [host] project called `SharedVPC` with a network `network01` and a subnet `serverless-subnet01: 10.200.12.0/28`
- The Shared VPC Project shares its networks and subnets with another project `project1`
- Nothing else is using `serverless-subnet01`
- All resources in both projects are in `us-central1`
- I have the `owner` role in both projects
- `vpcaccess.googleapis.com` is enabled in `project1`

### The issue:

I want to create a Serverless VPC Access Connector in `project1` using `network01` and `serverless-subnet01`, but when trying to follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to create a connector, the following error occurs after clicking "create" with `us-central1` as the region, `network01` as the network, and `serverless-subnet01` as the subnet:

```
Operation failed: VPC Access did not have permission to resolve the subnet or the provided subnet does not exist.
```

I have attempted to apply the troubleshooting steps in the documentation, with the following results:

1. <s>There is no such account with a name like `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-vpcaccess.iam.gserviceaccount.com` or the role of `roles/vpcaccess.serviceAgent` in either `project1` or `SharedVPC`</s> Edit: there is an account in `SharedVPC` with the name `service-SharedVPC_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-vpcaccess.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, but it is only visible through gcloud commands and adding the appropriate roles to it does not fix the issue.
2. No network overlaps with `serverless-subnet-01`,
3. There are no firewall rules with a priority over 1000 that denies ingress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that there was a vpc access service account for `project1`, but it was only visible through gcloud commands rather than the console. This account needs the  `roles/vpcaccess.serviceAgent` role in the shared vpc project in order to access the subnet.

Answer (score 0):

On the Console IAM page for the service project, before you can see this service account, you need to tick "Include Google-provided role grants".

> "Google-managed service accounts are used to access the APIs of Google
> Cloud Platform services."

If you still can't see `service-SharedVPC_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-vpcaccess.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, enable the Serverless VPC Access API `vpcaccess.googleapis.com` in the service project, as that is what creates this service account.